# Laravel send a request after a fixed time

Tags: ajax, laravel, cron, task, rate

im trying here to show a rating modal after 30min of the start of the appointement if the appointement duration is 30 , when the user clicks the button it sends him to an external page (google meet) after that i need to show a modal in the dashboard showing rate of the call is there any way i can do that from backend(laravel) or is there an api  from google meet i can use ? i tried with javascript it works fine but i need it to be backend . Thanks for any help

i tried with Carbon::addminutes from start time but i dont know how to get the response from the front

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to  create a job, check out https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#delayed-dispatching

Comment: thats the only way of achieving this ? what about the client side how its gonna show the modal ?